# PHP: How do I unescape user input from $_POST?

Tags: php

I have a PHP page receiving input from an HTML form via $_POST. The strings in $_POST have quotes and backslashes escaped with '\'. I don't know what else it will escape/encode. I'd like to have exactly what the user typed (as UTF-8 ideally) and I'm sure there's some simple function to do this, but I'm not sure which is the right one.

I know I have to be careful with this when I insert it into a database, or return it in the middle of some HTML, but in my code I'd like to have my hands on exactly what the user typed.

EDIT: magic_quotes_gpc was escaping some things, but even after removing that I still get HTML entities like &#260; from $_POST. Is there a simple way to decode $_POST back to the original user input (preferably in UTF-8)?

Comment: Processing post data securely and properly is an "extraordinarily narrow situation" is it? I can't believe how many good questions are closed on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try PHP's [stripslashes](https://www.php.net/stripslashes) function.

Just a side note, it sounds like you have magic_quotes_gpc on, which isn't recommended for security reasons, and it is even removed in later versions of PHP.

Comment: So magic_quotes_gpc is what's escaping stuff on me? How do I turn that off?

Comment: Yes, most likely. It's a configuration option in PHP, here's some more information about it: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I didn't have the charset properly set to UTF-8 on the page with the form. When I corrected this, everything came out ok.